# Shader that render canvas before any object

Tags: unity, c#, shaders

I have a canvas (in world space/3d) which is not showing to camera due to this shader which is applied to another (sphere) object.

```
Shader "Custom/TextureHolderCustom" {
    Properties {

        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Mask ("Mask Texture", 2D) = "white" {}

    }
    SubShader {
    Tags{"Queue" = "Transparent"}
       Cull Off
       Lighting On
       Zwrite On
       Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

       Pass
       {
       SetTexture[_Mask]{combine texture}
       SetTexture[_MainTex]{combine texture,previous}
       }
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

sphere object where my above shader is attached showing first but my canvas is not showing. I want to show the canvas first. I think i attach above shader to my canvas but it is not possible to apply m

*I am zero in shader programming*

Comment: Can you tell us more about how your scene is set up and why your canvas isn't showing right now? Is it that this sphere should be transparent, but it's rendering earlier and writing into the depth buffer, causing your canvas to fail the depth test when it tries to draw later?

Comment: Try changing https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-renderQueue.html to something over 3000 (that's over everything except the overlay) and below 4000 (overlay, you don't really want that canvas to render above particle effects, I assume), I can't really write a full answer right now but will try to do it tonight if I don't forget.